# How to show a progress spinner in android, when doInBackground() is being executed

Tags: android, android-asynctask

This is my Activity class where i use AsyncTask to get data from a server:

```
public class UserProfileActivity extends Activity {

    private ImageView userImage;
    private TextView userName;
    private TextView userLocation;
    private TextView editInfo;
    private TextView chnageImage;
    private TextView userScore;
    private ListView friendsList;
    public ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    public int score;
    public int level;
    public String image;
    public String fname;
    public String lname;
    public String city;
    public int id;
    public String email;
    protected Activity activity = this;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.user_profile);

        userImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profileImage);
        userName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.userName_profile);
        userLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.userLocation_profile);
        editInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.edit_profile);
        chnageImage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.changeImage_profile);
        userScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.userScore_profile);
        friendsList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.friendsList);

        new LongOperation().execute("");

    }

    private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        private InputStream is;
        private StringBuilder sb;
        private String result;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            try {
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                        "http://www.xxxxxxxxx.com/mobile/getProfileInfo");
                HttpResponse response = SignUpActivity.httpclient
                        .execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();

                try {
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                    sb = new StringBuilder();
                    sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
                    String line = "0";
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    is.close();
                    result = sb.toString();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(result);
                    String status = jObj.getString("status");
                    score = jObj.getInt("credits");
                    level = jObj.getInt("level");
                    image = jObj.getString("image");
                    fname = jObj.getString("fname");
                    lname = jObj.getString("lname");
                    city = jObj.getString("city");
                    id = jObj.getInt("user_id");
                    email = jObj.getString("email");

                    JSONArray friendsJsonArray = jObj.getJSONArray("friends");
                    int size = friendsJsonArray.length();

                    ArrayList<String> friendsNames = new ArrayList<String>();
                    String[] friendsIds = new String[size];
                    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

                        friendsNames.add(friendsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i)
                                .getString("name"));
                    }
                    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                            R.layout.simple_listview_item, friendsNames);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

            return "Executed";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            friendsList.setAdapter(adapter);
            userScore.setText(score + " points" + "   level " + level);
            userName.setText(fname + "  " + lname);
            userLocation.setText(city);
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            try {
                bitmap = BitmapFactory
                        .decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(image).getContent());
            } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {

                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e2) {

                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
            userImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        }
    }
}
```

when this activity is loaded it shows all the default values and images and then changes when background code execution is competed(as excepted), but this takes 2-3 secs for which user will be seeing default values, which i dont want to. So how can i keep a spinner like this:

[image]

for 2-3 secs and then when the spinner disappears the activity must show the actual values.

Thank you

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Refer the below code

```
private class FetchRSSFeeds extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(HomeActivity.this);

    /** progress dialog to show user that the backup is processing. */
    /** application context. */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.dialog.setMessage("Please wait");
        this.dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args) {
        try {

            Utilities.arrayRSS = objRSSFeed
                    .FetchRSSFeeds(Constants.Feed_URL);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("tag", "error", e);
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {

        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

        // Setting data to list adapter
        setListData();
    }
```

Comment: can you also please tell me how to make this progressDialog appear only on a particular view??... like i have an activity with TextViews and a ListView. TextViews are easily populated but ListView takes time to get data. So i want this ProgressDialog to appear just on the ListView??

Comment: You have to show ProgressDialog while fetching data from server in background. Not for particular view

Comment: by not you mean i cant??...because in some apps they show 3-4 ProgressDialogs on the same activity.will try to upload pics of that app

Comment: You can do that. For that you have to call another Asynctask. After one is completed call another

Comment: yeah but how to small progress dialog on the listview alone??....any other buttons or textview on the same activity will be active while on listview is overlapped by this progressdialog

Answer (score 13):

Do This:-

1. **Declare** the ProgressDialog at the Top.

   ```
   ProgressDialog pd;
   ```
2. **Start** it in **onPreExecute** Method of Async Task.

   ```
   pd=ProgressDialog.show(ActivityName.this,"","Please Wait",false);
   ```
3. **Stop** it in the **onPostExecute** Method.

   ```
   pd.dismiss();
   ```

Answer (score 0):

In onCreate method call some like below

```
mdialog=new Dialog(this);
 new LongOperation().execute("");
```

Then override onPostExecute of AyncTask

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

       @Override
       public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mdialog.dismiss();
       }
      });
        }
```

Comment: `onPostExecute` runs on the UI thread by design. Adding the `runOnUiThread` call is redundant in this case.