# Progress bar is not shown while AsyncTask is working

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-progressbar

I'm trying to implement a progress bar into my application which is shown while my `AsyncTask` is fetching data.

For this I tried to rebuild this SO-Answer (["SO: How to show a progress spinner"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11752961/how-to-show-a-progress-spinner-in-android-when-doinbackground-is-being-execut)).

But my progress bar is shown up (and instantly dismissed) on the end of my `AsyncTask` when all the work is already done. "Peter" ask a similar answer ["here"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12001995/progressdialog-not-shown-in-asynctask) more than a year ago but didn't get a heling answer.

This is my `AsyncTask`. Info: `AppActivity` is the parent class of all the activities in my application. Some contain fragments, some not. Some use my `RESTTask`.

```
public class RESTTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

  protected AppActivity AppActivity;

  /*
   * Special constructor to pass the activity
   */
  public RESTTask(AppActivity activity) {
    AppActivity = activity;
  }  

  @Override
  protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    String resultstring = "";

    // fetch data from a webservice

    return resultstring;
  }


  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute() {

    super.onPreExecute();

    if (AppActivity != null) {
      AppActivity.showDialog();
    }

  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    if (AppActivity != null) {
      AppActivity.dismissDialog();
    }

  }

}
```

My `AppActivity`:

```
public class AppActivity extends Activity {

  public ProgressDialog dialog;

  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
  }

  public void showDialog() {
    this.dialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.Please_wait));
    this.dialog.show();
  }

  public void dismissDialog() {
    if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
      this.dialog.dismiss();
    }
  }

}
```

So my question is now: How to correctly implement the progress bar so it's shown up WHILE the `AsyncTask` is performing and not only after it ?

updated info: I hope this example makes it clearer what does not work as expected:

In one of my activities (exact in one of the fragments of one of my activites) I want to call a webservice. The webservice-method takes about ten seconds to answer because of it's complexitiy. So I expect to see the progress bar to be shown from the moment the webservice is called until the answer is recieved. But what I can see while debuging is the following:

1. The `onPreExecute` is called and the dialog should be shown, but the emulator only shows a white screen
2. The `doInBackground` is called. In eclipse' `LogCat` I see that the webservice is called and the result is dealt with. Screen is still. When calling the webservice the emulator stills shows a white screen.
3. The `onPostExecute` is called to dismiss the dialog. At the beginning of the `onPostExecute` the final rendered screen is shown.
4. After resuming from the `onPostExecute` the dialog flashs up and is closed instantly after that.

Hope this helps to understand the problem.

edit: Updated source code after fixed the error with the `leak window`-exception. Also updated question for hopefully make it clearer.

[2]: [Activity has leaked window that was originally added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850573/activity-has-leaked-window-that-was-originally-added) "SO: Leaked window exception

Comment: Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821423/background-task-progress-dialog-orientation-change-is-there-any-100-working. It worked very well for me.

Comment: You have not return an string in `doInBackground` method and You can't handle UI in `doInBackground`.

Comment: @st. Checked it and it couldn't help me :/

Comment: Updated my question after the `leaked window` problem was solved and add some info about my problem to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2):

**1.** Your `onPostExecute()` *is Never called*

*Because* you returns String from `protected String doInBackground(Void... params)`

And you have `protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success)`

*So Change to*

```
 @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
       this.dialog.dismiss();
      }  
  }
```

**2.** you can't *Handle/update* `UI part` in `doInBackground()`

So *remove following from* `doInBackground()`

```
if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
      this.dialog.dismiss();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the notice about the `onPostExecute`. I changed this so one of the problems (the `leaked windows`-exception) has gone. But the progressbar still pops up and instantly disappears at the end of the `AsynchTask` work. Do you have any idea for this either?

Answer (score 1):

display your dialog in `onPreExecute()`

try this code

```
class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        super.onPreExecute();
        //display dialog here
        dialog.show();

    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //do your stuff here
        return myString;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        super.onPostExecute(result);
        //dismiss dialog here
        dialog.dismiss();
    }

}
```